# Good datastructure for look up of an id mapping to set of elements (c++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

No boost, just plain STL please.

I have a class Foo* mapping to a set of pointers of class ID.

and I need to map a pointer to an  instance  of ID to a FOO class.

say I have this function:

```
void FindXXX(const ID* pID)
{

 /*find the containing FOO class quickly, but not at expense of an ugly code*/

}
```

right now I map each ID* to FOO* thus having something like that

map myMap; which I think is kind of ugly and redundant.

Please suggest

Comment: What warrants a downvote? Please advice how  can I improve the quality of this question to earn your upvote?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that each ID corresponds to a single Foo? If so, could the class ID contain a pointer to the set it belongs to? Then it would be enough to keep a map of set* => Foo*.

Comment: yes, it is guaranteed. However, keeping set* => foo, won't allow you queries such as find instance of FOO* for a specific ID*

Comment: But if each ID logically belongs to one FOO, why don't you just include a pointer to FOO as a member variable in ID?

Comment: cuz I cannot modify  those classes.

Comment: In this case, I don't see why you think your current solution ugly and redundant. It's not.

Comment: Why not boost? Just for information.

Comment: cuz we don't link against boost for production builds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> right now I map each ID* to FOO* thus
>   having something like that
>
> map myMap; which I think is kind of
>   ugly and redundant.

I assume you have something like this:

```
map<ID*, Foo*> myMap;
```

Why would that be ugly?

Comment: Please post comments into the comment section of my question. thank you... because I store the same instance of Foo* for many, many, IDs, as each ID logically belongs to Foo*

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for std::map, but your remarks seem to indicate that you don't want to use one, is that true?

```
std::map <key_type, data_type, [comparison_function]>
```

Comment: incorrect I do want to use one, just don't know how to set it up correctly. The one I already have seems like it wasting lots space as I store repeated Foo* for  multiple ID's

Comment: Well, it is a hash, so it will consume more space by default than a simple array.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it kind of depends on the size of the two sets (ID* and foo*). I assume that you have #ID >> #FOO, and #FOO big enough to not warrant linear search through them.

I assume ID <-> Foo is a 1-to-many mapping.

You could store the mapping as a set > > and sort them this way:
the set is sorted in increasing order of ID* (pointer value order would be fine)
the set> is sorted in ascending order of the value of the first ID* in the .second of the pair.

When searching, you need to find the range of Foo* that have a set where the first ID* has a (pointer) value lower than the searched-for item, and the last a value higher. This will result in a hopefully much smaller set of items to iterate over their set. 
Then, iterate over these and find the one that contains the ID* you are looking for.

You will need a comparator for the pair > like this:

```
typedef Item pair<Foo*, set<ID*> >;

// Sorter in ascending order of first ID*, then ascending order of last ID*
struct IDOrdering: public binary_function<Item, Item, bool> {
  bool operator ()(const Item& lhs, const Item& rhs) {
    return *(lhs.second.begin()) < *(rhs.second.begin())
        || *(lhs.second.rbegin()) < *(rhs.second.rbegin());
  }
};


// your global map
set<Item, FirstIDOrdering> myMap;
typedef set<Item, FirstIDOrdering>::iterator ItemIterator;

// search for the item
Foo* FindXXX(const ID* pId) {
   Item criterion;
   criterion.second.insert(pId);
   ItemIterator start = myMap.lower_bound(criterion);
   while (start != myMap.end() && *(start->second.rbegin()) > pId) {
     if (start->second.count(pId))
       return start->first;
   }
   return NULL;
}
```

You may save some memory here, as Foo* and ID* are stored only once, but it comes at the cost of some complexity and probably some performance.

Note that this example does not take into account all sorts of border cases (empty lists), and you have to be careful when inserting a new item into the global myMap, as you may be able to add a new ID* to the list of a pair<>, but you need to make sure the entire set is sorted again, so that the find will actually work.

It is, however, difficult to know what would be best for you, as there is very little info about what you try to achieve: are the Foo* in the millions, the ID* in the millions, is this function to resolve ID* to Foo*  called often ? In a performance critical section of your system ? All these are useful to make the trade-offs for the readability, complexity and performance of the code.